# Filter on relation field in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a model Media that has a relationship to a model UserMedia (user ratings). Also there's a model called UserMatchScore (match scores of users) that is relevant to the question.

In a view I am querying the Media table, in this view there's an option to only get the media that my matches have rated, but I haven't rated. Also an average of ratings is returned based on the subset of me and my matches, not all users that have rated the media. I do this with annotation.

What I do is filter the Media table for elements that I haven't rated, but my matches have rated, this is simple, but it only does half of the job. All media is returned that I haven't rated, but my matches have rated, but the relational field UserMedia still contains all ratings, this one isn't filtered, so there's no way to calculate the average of ratings for the subset of my matches.
Here's the query I am describing:

```
queryset = models.Media.objects
queryset = queryset.filter(
               Q(usermedia__user__id__in=my_matches) & ~Q(usermedia__user=user)
            )
```

The only way to get to the expected result is to loop through the queryset and filter each element of the UserMedia relation, but this is too slow, so has to be done with a DB query.

```
for el in queryset:                    
    el.usermedia_set.filter(~Q(user=user)).filter(user=my_matches)
```

Does anyone know how to do this with Django ORM?

Comment: Why are you using Q objects in all your queries? Aren't they useless in these examples?

Comment: Continuing @Lotram comment - wouldn't condition `.filter(usermedia__user_id__in=my_matches)` be enough, or can user be in their own matches? And regarding the question, as it's not entirely clear for me - your issue is how to annotate each `Media` with average rating by user's matches?

Comment: `~Q()` is useful for NOT including, `Q()` can be omitted.

Comment: In your second query, you can use `.exclude()` instead of `.filter(~Q)`

Comment: @mfrackowiak the `UserMedia` can contain ratings from users that are/aren't my matches. I want to filter out users that aren't my matches (so that the average is calculated on this subset). The query right now returns Media that has been rated by my matches and not by me, which is one half of the job. I need to also filter out each entry of UserMedia from users that aren't in my matches (what I do with the for loop. I can edit the question with example if further clarification is needed.

Comment: @Lotram By second query you mean the one inside of the loop? The thing is that I can't use the loop, it is too slow...

Comment: I agree with @mfrackowiak , it seems you need to use annotates, like the examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses).

Comment: I do use annotation to calculate the average, but I need to calculate the average on the correct subset of UserMedia, not on all UserMedia for a given Media.

Comment: The problem is that the query returns Media that I have not rated, but my matches do, this is 1/2 of the job. I also need to filter the relational field UserMedia (why I use the for loop).

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations)? Like `Media.objects.filter(usermedia__user_id__in=my_matches).exclude(user=user).annotate(avg_rating=Avg('usermdia__rating', filter=Q(usermedia__user_id__in=mymatches))`
Not sure it works, but the filter keyword seems designed to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188281/discussion-between-ben-gosub-and-lotram).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) you can get the related objects for a relation (for many-to-many and reverse foreign key relations) using a pre-filtered queryset:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(
               Q(usermedia__user__id__in=my_matches) & ~Q(usermedia__user=user)
            )

prefetch = UserMedia.objects.filter(user_id__in=my_matches).exclude(user=user)
queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('usermedia_set', prefetch, to_attr='filtered_usermedia')
)

for el in queryset:
    for usermedia in el.filtered_usermedia:
        # iterate over the filtered usermedia
        # without any additional queries
        calculate_something(usermedia)
```

Note that this will result in one additional query for prefetching all related objects (so a total of two queries, no matter how many rows you fetch), compared to one additional query before for every object in the main queryset.

Comment: Great answer, there's only one shortcoming, prefetch puts 'filtered_usermedia' into a list, not a queryset. And I need to be able to run Avg on this subset, not possible to run it on a list. Of course I want to avoid the for loop because the performance is very low.

Comment: I see that I can avout the `to_attr` argument, so this is the proffered way to do what I need. Thank you very much!